# React-Native webRTC works wrong

Tags: react-native, websocket, webrtc

I've got a project, coded a component, but it works stange.

functionality:
[4 pages, random id for signaling websocket server identification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sHCu.jpg)

Code:

```
const Call = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [localStream, setlocalStream] = useState(null)
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState(new MediaStream())
  const [localMicOn, setlocalMicOn] = useState(true)
  const [localWebcamOn, setlocalWebcamOn] = useState(true)

  const [type, setType] = useState('JOIN')

  const [callerId] = useState(
    Math.floor(100 + Math.random() * 900).toString(),
  )

  const otherUserId = useRef(null)
  const socket = useRef(null)

  const pc = useRef(new RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }]
  }))

  const candidates = useRef([])
  const remoteRTCMessage = useRef(null)

  function answerCall(data) {
    socket.current.emit('answerCall', data);
  }

  function sendCall(data) {
    socket.current.emit('call', data);
  }

  function sendICEcandidate(data) {
    socket.current.emit('iICEcandidate', data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = SocketIOClient('http://myserver.com:3500', {
      transports: ['websocket'], query: { callerId }
    })

    socket.current.on('newCall', data => {
      console.log('\n newCall data: \n', data)

      remoteRTCMessage.current = data.rtcMessage
      otherUserId.current = data.callerId
      setType('INCOMING_CALL')
    })

    socket.current.on('callAnswered', data => {
      console.log('\n callAnswered data: \n', candidates)
      remoteRTCMessage.current = data.rtcMessage
      pc.current.setRemoteDescription(data.rtcMessage)
      setType('WEBRTC_ROOM')
    })

    socket.current.on('oICEcandidate', data => {
      if (pc.current.remoteDescription !== null) {
        pc.current.addIceCandidate(
          new RTCIceCandidate({
            candidate: data.rtcMessage.candidate,
            sdpMid: data.rtcMessage.id,
            sdpMLineIndex: data.rtcMessage.label,
          }))
          .then(data => { console.log('\n oICEcandidate ice SUCCESS \n') })
          .catch(err => { console.log('\n ICEERROR \n', err) })
      } else {
        candidates.current.push(data.rtcMessage)
      }
      console.log('\n oICEcandidate data: \n', data)
    })

  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    pc.current.addEventListener('connectionstatechange', event => {
      console.log('\n listener connectionstatechange event: \n', event)
    })

    pc.current.addEventListener('icecandidate', event => {
      console.log('\n listener icecandidate event: \n', event)

      if (!event.candidate) {
        return
      } else {
        sendICEcandidate({
          calleeId: otherUserId.current,
          rtcMessage: {
            label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
            id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
            candidate: event.candidate.candidate,
          },
        })
      }
    })

    pc.current.addEventListener('icecandidateerror', event => {
      console.log('\n listener icecandidateerror event: \n', event)
    })

    pc.current.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', event => {
      console.log('\n listener iceconnectionstatechange event: \n', event)
    })

    pc.current.addEventListener('negotiationneeded', event => {
      console.log('\n listener negotiationneeded event: \n', event)

      pc.current.createOffer()
        .then(offer => {
          pc.current.setLocalDescription(offer)
          return Promise.resolve(offer)
        })
        .then(offer => {
          sendCall({
            calleeId: otherUserId.current,
            rtcMessage: offer,
          })
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    })

    pc.current.addEventListener('signalingstatechange', event => {
      console.log('\n listener signalingstatechange event: \n', event)
    })

    pc.current.addEventListener('track', event => {
      console.log('\n listener track event: \n', event)
      const newStream = remoteStream
      newStream.addTrack(event.track)
      setRemoteStream(newStream)
    })
  }, [])

  const processCall = async () => {
    let mediaConstraints = {
      audio: true,
      video: {
        frameRate: 30,
        facingMode: 'user'
      }
    }

    try {
      const mediaStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
      setlocalStream(mediaStream)

      mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        pc.current.addTrack(track, mediaStream)
      })

      //console.log("\nDEBUG\n", pc.current)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(console.log('\n processCall error: \n', err))
    }
  }

  const processAccept = async () => {
    let mediaConstraints = {
      audio: true,
      video: {
        frameRate: 30,
        facingMode: 'user'
      }
    }

    try {
      pc.current.setRemoteDescription(remoteRTCMessage.current)

      const answer = await pc.current.createAnswer()
      await pc.current.setLocalDescription(answer)

      const mediaStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
      setlocalStream(mediaStream)

      answerCall({
        callerId: otherUserId.current,
        rtcMessage: answer,
      })

      candidates.current.map(candidate => pc.current.addIceCandidate(
        new RTCIceCandidate({
          candidate: candidate.candidate,
          sdpMid: candidate.id,
          sdpMLineIndex: candidate.label,
        }))
        .then(data => { console.log('\n processAccept ice SUCCESS \n') })
        .catch(err => { console.log('Errorseew', err) })
      )

      candidates.current = []
      //console.log("\nDEBUG\n", pc.current)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(console.log('\n processCall error: \n', err))
    }
  }

  function switchCamera() {
    localStream.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => {
      track._switchCamera()
    })
  }

  function toggleCamera() {
    localWebcamOn ? setlocalWebcamOn(false) : setlocalWebcamOn(true)
    localStream.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => {
      localWebcamOn ? (track.enabled = false) : (track.enabled = true)
    })
  }

  function toggleMic() {
    localMicOn ? setlocalMicOn(false) : setlocalMicOn(true)
    localStream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => {
      localMicOn ? (track.enabled = false) : (track.enabled = true)
    })
  }

  function leave() {
    pc.current.close()
    setlocalStream(null)
    setType('JOIN')
  }
```

UI code:

```
const JoinScreen = () => {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#050A0E',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          paddingHorizontal: 42,
        }}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <>
            <View
              style={{
                padding: 35,
                backgroundColor: '#1A1C22',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                borderRadius: 14,
              }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: '#D0D4DD',
                }}>
                Your Caller ID
              </Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  marginTop: 12,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 32,
                    color: '#ffff',
                    letterSpacing: 6,
                  }}>
                  {callerId}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>

            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#1A1C22',
                padding: 40,
                marginTop: 25,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                borderRadius: 14,
              }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: '#D0D4DD',
                }}>
                Enter call id of another user
              </Text>
              <TextInputContainer
                placeholder={'Enter Caller ID'}
                value={otherUserId.current}
                setValue={text => {
                  otherUserId.current = text;
                  console.log('TEST', otherUserId.current);
                }}
                keyboardType={'number-pad'}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  setType('OUTGOING_CALL')
                  processCall()
                }}
                style={{
                  height: 50,
                  backgroundColor: '#5568FE',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  borderRadius: 12,
                  marginTop: 16,
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                  }}>
                  Call Now
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  };

  const OutgoingCallScreen = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
          backgroundColor: '#050A0E',
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            padding: 35,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            borderRadius: 14,
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 16,
              color: '#D0D4DD',
            }}>
            Calling to...
          </Text>

          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 36,
              marginTop: 12,
              color: '#ffff',
              letterSpacing: 6,
            }}>
            {otherUserId.current}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              setType('JOIN');
              otherUserId.current = null;
            }}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#FF5D5D',
              borderRadius: 30,
              height: 60,
              aspectRatio: 1,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <CallEnd width={50} height={12} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const IncomingCallScreen = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
          backgroundColor: '#050A0E',
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            padding: 35,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            borderRadius: 14,
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 36,
              marginTop: 12,
              color: '#ffff',
            }}>
            {otherUserId.current} is calling..
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              processAccept()
              setType('WEBRTC_ROOM')
            }}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'green',
              borderRadius: 30,
              height: 60,
              aspectRatio: 1,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <CallAnswer height={28} fill={'#fff'} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const WebrtcRoomScreen = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#050A0E',
          paddingHorizontal: 12,
          paddingVertical: 12,
        }}>
        {localStream ? (
          <RTCView
            objectFit={'cover'}
            style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#050A0E' }}
            streamURL={localStream.toURL()}
          />
        ) : null}
        {remoteStream ? (
          <RTCView
            objectFit={'cover'}
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: '#050A0E',
              marginTop: 8,
            }}
            streamURL={remoteStream.toURL()}
          />
        ) : null}
        <View
          style={{
            marginVertical: 12,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
          }}>
          <IconContainer
            backgroundColor={'red'}
            onPress={() => {
              leave()
            }}
            Icon={() => {
              return <CallEnd height={26} width={26} fill="#FFF" />;
            }}
          />
          <IconContainer
            style={{
              borderWidth: 1.5,
              borderColor: '#2B3034',
            }}
            backgroundColor={!localMicOn ? '#fff' : 'transparent'}
            onPress={() => {
              toggleMic()
            }}
            Icon={() => {
              return localMicOn ? (
                <MicOn height={24} width={24} fill="#FFF" />
              ) : (
                <MicOff height={28} width={28} fill="#1D2939" />
              );
            }}
          />
          <IconContainer
            style={{
              borderWidth: 1.5,
              borderColor: '#2B3034',
            }}
            backgroundColor={!localWebcamOn ? '#fff' : 'transparent'}
            onPress={() => {
              toggleCamera()
            }}
            Icon={() => {
              return localWebcamOn ? (
                <VideoOn height={24} width={24} fill="#FFF" />
              ) : (
                <VideoOff height={36} width={36} fill="#1D2939" />
              );
            }}
          />
          <IconContainer
            style={{
              borderWidth: 1.5,
              borderColor: '#2B3034',
            }}
            backgroundColor={'transparent'}
            onPress={() => {
              switchCamera()
            }}
            Icon={() => {
              return <CameraSwitch height={24} width={24} fill="#FFF" />;
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  switch (type) {
    case 'JOIN':
      return JoinScreen();
    case 'INCOMING_CALL':
      return IncomingCallScreen();
    case 'OUTGOING_CALL':
      return OutgoingCallScreen();
    case 'WEBRTC_ROOM':
      return WebrtcRoomScreen();
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

export default Call
```

when person A starts a call and person B accepts it, person B can hear person A, person A doesn't hear person B. I swapped them. it's the same but mirrored. I've wasted 30h trying to fix it. Feel terrible.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you have only one offer-answer exchange during the signalling.

Here is why it won't work in this case:

1. User A creates RTCPeerConnection; adds its audio track and sends an offer to user B. This offer contains SDP with information that user A wants to send audio and it presents what codecs and other audio parameters it supports.
2. User B receives the offer, adds it's own media track and sends an answer. Answer will contain user B's media details as well as *the chosen media parameters for user A's audio*.
3. User A receives the answer. Now it knows what parameters to use for sending audio and can start sending. It also receives information that user B wants to send its own audio and gets supported parameters.

The problem here is that user B has presented its supported codecs but never receives information from A what parameters should it use to encode the audio. It results in B not sending audio at all.

An easy fix for that would be to generate and send another offer when RTCPeerConnection is established.

Comment: do you mean to send another offer from user B to user A after we send offer form A to B and establish RTCPeerConnection?
Could you please point out on my code where i should fix it? I would be extremely grateful

Comment: No, you should sent one more offer from A to B after you've received answer from B. I think you can do it in your `socket.current.on('callAnswered',...)` callback. Create a new offer and send it to the other user one more time. Make sure B will set this offer with `setRemoteDescription`